# Why Update contacts methods does nothing in android

Tags: android

I write an Update method to update contacts but after i run this on my phone nothing happen
and no contact get update why?

this is my method :

```
public Boolean UpdateContacts(ArrayList<ContactInfo> encryptedContactsInfoList) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new   ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ContentResolver cr = null;
    for (ContactInfo contactInfo : encryptedContactsInfoList) {

        try {


            String contactId = contactInfo.getContactID();
            String contactName = contactInfo.getContactName();
            String contactNumber = contactInfo.getContactNumber();


            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(
                             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID
                                    + " = ?",  new String[] { contactId })
                     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            "asdffgh").build());

               cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);



        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    return true;
 }
```

this is ops after executing the code:

```
 [{"mSelection":"_id \u003d ?","mSelectionArgs":["2302"],"mUri":{"authority":    


{"decoded":"com.android.contacts","encoded":"com.android.contacts"},"fragment":{},"path":  


{"decoded":"NOT CACHED","encoded":"/data"},"query":{},"scheme":"content","uriString":"NOT   


CACHED","host":"NOT CACHED","port":-2},"mValues":{"mValues":      


{"display_name":"asdffgh"}},"mType":2,"mYieldAllowed":false}]
```

any help really appreciate,

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You get nothing because your `ContentResolver` is null, so you get an exception in every iteration.

Your app does not crash because you have `catch (Exception e)` that catches every exception.

try with:

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
```

also, the applyBatch call should be after the for loop, otherwise you are procesing many times every item, and change `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID` to  `ContactsContract.Data._ID`

```
 try {


  for (ContactInfo contactInfo : encryptedContactsInfoList) {

         String contactId = contactInfo.getContactID();
        String contactName = contactInfo.getContactName();
        String contactNumber = contactInfo.getContactNumber();


        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(
                         ContactsContract.Data._ID
                                + " = ?",  new String[] { contactId })
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        "asdffgh").build());
    }

     cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);


    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.but how can i handle it?what should i do then?

Comment: I did what you said .but nothing happen again.

Comment: @user3026622 open the logcat and look for the exception text. you will have the info of the error. if you dont understand it, paste the logcat text in the question

Comment: i logged all exceptoins but there is no exception there.

Comment: i'm writting this method in a class which extends service,should i write this in an activity class?

Comment: it is ok in a service. if you execute the code step by step, or you use a breakpoint,  you dont get into the catch block?

Comment: yes there is an exception:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x18d6408 on this line   cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

Comment: @user3026622 thats because ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID is not a valid column. change it to ContactsContract.Data._ID